# After pushing my code from the production server to a gitlab repository, I have a problem with postgresql and migrations in my django webapp

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

Now maybe I'm getting this wrong but here's my story :

Today, i decide to get the code that I've been writing in an uncontrolled manner on the production server to a gitlab repository.

So I create the repository on gitlab and push my code using

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/xxxxxx
git branch -M master
git push -uf origin master
```

A few hours later I notice my django webapp is down and when i check in the error logs, it coincides roughly with the work I was doing on gitlab

The error message I get is

2023-08-08 21:26:31,218: Error running WSGI application
2023-08-08 21:26:31,226: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'

I reinstalled the module with

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Then i get the error message

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "app_pageview" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."app_pageview"."url", "app_pageview"."count" FROM "app_pagev...
```

pageview is a middleware I create to log the number of pageviews per page to the database

I have a look in the database with

```
python3 manage.py dbshell
\dt
```

and I see that there are no tables relating to the pageviews in the database

So I think , maybe if I see what is going on with the migrations

```
python3 manage.py migrate --plan
```

and this gives an error message

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency app.0001_initial on database 'default'
```

And at this point I say, time to go to stackoverflow before I cause some serious damage as I don't really know what I'm doing

You can see the error message on https://www.clare-energy.ie

many thanks if you have some pointers

/ Colm

Comment: Habe you run the initial migrations after installing psycop? `python3 manage.py migrate`

Comment: Hello Marco, it gives the same error message
    django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency app.0001_initial on database 'default'

Comment: Can you resolve the migration dependency issue to run the migrations? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#dependencies